# Gabor filter and image processing

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, wavelet, gabor-filter

I am learning to use gabor filters to extract features from images and I have the following questions: According to the introduction in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter, gabor filter is a complex function which has real and imaginary parts. But we only use the real part as a filter, so why? And what is the use of the imaginary part?

Comment: Please read [ask], and limit each post to a single, answerable question. -- Regarding question 1, you are misunderstanding: both real and imaginary components must be used. Often the magnitude of the complex output of the filter is used, to remove phase information and retain only amplitude information.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! I will modify my post. According to the python implementation of gabor filter on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Example_implementations, only the real part is used, and it claims that "the two components may be formed into a complex number or used individually."

Comment: That implementation is wrong. If you use only the real part it's not a Gabor filter. Also, I doubt the usefulness of its output.